# How to choose between hooking into per_get_posts or into parse_query

Tags: wp-query, hooks, pre-get-posts

In refactoring my code base I noticed there are two hooks that used for modifying the main query.

- `parse_query`
- `pre_get_posts`

From the [Plugin API Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) it seems these hooks fire back to back and both have access to the main WP_Query object.  I need to know how they are different in order to determine which one is the proper choice for my needs.  The developer docs for [parse_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_query/) and [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) don't provide sufficient information to answer this question.

The code that uses `parse_query` is based on [an article on filtering admin listings based on a custom fields](https://newbedev.com/filter-by-custom-field-in-custom-post-type-on-admin-page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking real hard at the code around both hooks, and they run one right after the other, with the same arguments, and I just can't see any meaningful difference.

*Theoretically* only `parse_query` would run, and not `pre_get_posts`, if `WP_Query::parse_query()` were to be run directly on its own, but WordPress itself never does that. Maybe some plugins do, but I don't know why they would. Near as I can tell there's no technical reason to use one over the other, but `pre_get_posts` is newer, much more widely used, and much better documented, officially and by third parties. I suspect `parse_query` is somewhat vestigial.

I'd suggest using `pre_get_posts`. Any code you see using `parse_query` should work as-is with `pre_get_posts`.